# Printing from Linux to a raw CUPS queue

Tags: linux, cups

I have a CUPS server running on a Raspberry PI which is connected to a Brother HL 5340D printer. Because the PI's CPU is so feeble I have setup CUPS to share a raw queue. My plan was to have my beefier Linux desktop do the rendering work and then sending the result to the PI. I tried connecting to the raw queue from my desktop using the manufacturer provided PPD file but when I tried to print I got garbage output.

Obviously I do not have a good handle on CUPS works. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup with cups (using airprint for my iphones on raspberry pi). Try "lpr" on the command line to test basic printing capabilities after printing a test page within cups web interface:

```
df | lpr
```

prints the file system statistics on your standard printer in text mode.